# A question related to financial planning

Tags: algebra-precalculus, finance

The total income of Vijay and Vipin is (INR) ₹$9,50,000$. The percentage of their expenses is $80$ and $85$. If the ratio of their saving is $6:5$, then find the saving of each of them.

I know that $\operatorname{savings} = \operatorname{income} - \operatorname{expenditure}$

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange. You are more likely to get answers rather than downvotes or votes to close if you edit the question to show us what you tried and where you are stuck. Could you solve easier problems (perhaps if the expenses or savings ratio were the same)? Use mathjax for mathematics: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: is that $9,500,000$?

Comment: No it is $9,50,000$

Comment: No one understands lakhs or crores of  Indian number system in US or Europe . Also please say Rupees instead of INR. And dont forget to mention what  you have tried so far in solving it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider
$$I_{VJ}+I_{VP}=9,500,000$$ 
$$\frac{I_{VJ}\cdot(1-0.8)}{I_{VP}\cdot(1-0.85)}=\frac65$$
Can you proceed from here?

Comment: Yes, sure. I got the answer.